# What is the most efficient way to read the first line of a file separately to the rest of the file?

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I am trying to figure out the best way to read the contents of a file. The problem is that I need to read the first line separately, because I need that to be parsed as a `usize` which I need for the dimension of a `Array2` by `ndarray`.

I tried the following:

```
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use std::io:{BufRead,BufReader};
use std::fs;


fn read_inputfile(geom_filename: &str) -> (Vec<i32>, Array2<f64>, usize) {
    //* Step 1: Read the coord data from input
    println!("Inputfile: {geom_filename}");

    let geom_file = fs::File::open(geom_filename).expect("Geometry file not found!");
    let geom_file_reader = BufReader::new(geom_file);
    let geom_file_lines: Vec<String> = geom_file_reader
        .lines()
        .map(|line| line.expect("Failed to read line!"))
        .collect();

    //* Read no of atoms first for array size
    let no_atoms: usize = geom_file_lines[0].parse().unwrap();

    let mut Z_vals: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    let mut geom_matr: Array2<f64> = Array2::zeros((no_atoms, 3));

    for (atom_idx, line) in geom_file_lines[1..].iter().enumerate() {
        //* into_iter would do the same
        let line_split: Vec<&str> = line.split_whitespace().collect();

        Z_vals.push(line_split[0].parse().unwrap());

        (0..3).for_each(|cart_coord| {
            geom_matr[(atom_idx, cart_coord)] = line_split[cart_coord + 1].parse().unwrap();
        });
    }

    (Z_vals, geom_matr, no_atoms)
}
```

Does this not kind of defeat the purpose of the `BufReader`? I am still relative new to Rust, so I might have misunderstood something, but I thought that one uses the `BufReader` so that the whole file does not need to be read into memory.

With the `Vec<String>` for `geom_file_lines` I am mostlike loading the whole file into memory again, right?

Comment: Why don't you make use of [BufRead::read_line](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) function, which is implemented for BufReader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this not kind of defeat the purpose of the `BufReader`?

It very much does, yes. `lines()` gives you an iterator, so you can read them **without** loading all of them into memory at once. You force them all into memory, though, as you call `collect()`.

Simply don't do that. Use the iterator as an iterator. Especially as you convert it **back** to an iterator later, via `geom_file_lines[1..].iter()`.

Like this:

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use std::fs;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

pub fn read_inputfile(geom_filename: &str) -> (Vec<i32>, Array2<f64>, usize) {
    //* Step 1: Read the coord data from input
    println!("Inputfile: {geom_filename}");

    let geom_file = fs::File::open(geom_filename).expect("Geometry file not found!");
    let geom_file_reader = BufReader::new(geom_file);
    let mut geom_file_lines = geom_file_reader
        .lines()
        .map(|line| line.expect("Failed to read line!"));

    //* Read no of atoms first for array size
    let no_atoms: usize = geom_file_lines.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();

    let mut z_vals: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    let mut geom_matr: Array2<f64> = Array2::zeros((no_atoms, 3));

    for (atom_idx, line) in geom_file_lines.enumerate() {
        let line_split: Vec<&str> = line.split_whitespace().collect();

        z_vals.push(line_split[0].parse().unwrap());

        (0..3).for_each(|cart_coord| {
            geom_matr[(atom_idx, cart_coord)] = line_split[cart_coord + 1].parse().unwrap();
        });
    }

    (z_vals, geom_matr, no_atoms)
}
```

---

You can apply the same logic in your `for` loop:

```rust
    for (atom_idx, line) in geom_file_lines.enumerate() {
        let mut line_split = line.split_whitespace();

        z_vals.push(line_split.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap());

        (0..3).for_each(|cart_coord| {
            geom_matr[(atom_idx, cart_coord)] = line_split.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for also adding the comment about the `for` loop. Coming from Python, I still need more concise usage of Iterators.